Type annotations lost when using zip and enumerate
Why am I missing type annotations after using enumerate and zip? I have following code:
for _, (free_surface, u_value, alpha_value) in enumerate(zip(self.free_surfaces, self.tank_u_values, self.tank_alpha_values):

self.free_surfaces: NDArray[bool_]
self.tank_u_values: NDArray[float64]
self.tank_alpha_values: NDArray[float64]

Now my problem is, that VS Code doesn't display the correct type annotations for these three variables, which are returned from enumerate():
free_surface, u_value and alpha_value.
These variables should hold the same type as in the array but VS Code displays them as type Any.
Is there something I'm interpreting wrong about type annotations?
Is this statement too complex for the editor to handle the correct type annotations?
Do zip or enumerate not forward type annotations of the Iterables?

it is only problem with VS Code not with Python. Simply VS Code is not so clever to recognize what types have new variables. But I wouldn't bother this. Annotations are not assigned to Python variables - Python doesn't care of it. And Numpy Array NDArray keeps information about type.

Thanks for your comment. I know, that the real datatype of the variable will be kept, but it's a pity whilst developing a rather bigger software, if somewhere in the code some type annotations are lost.
I'll have a look into other development environments which might provide better support for type annotations.
